# md-list-item with ng-click does not work in directive

Tags: angularjs, html, typescript, angular-material

**What I am trying to do:**

I am trying to create a generic way of creating a md-list. the list will be based on the input that is within it's html tags. For creating this list I am using `ng-transclude`. The programming language that I am using is `TypeScript`. TypeScript is compiled to `ES5`.

**Versions that I a using:**

Angular: 1.5.6

angular-aria: 1.5.6

angular-material: 1.0.9

---

**Problem**

I am trying to add an `ng-click` event to a `md-list-item`. The function the click event binds to is bound by the directive's scope. When I try to run the code the `ng-click` element does not appear on the `md-list-item`. Logically a click on the list item does not trigger any event.

I think that the reason the `ng-click` element is not set on the `md-list-item` is because of the aria warning that I am getting. It is as follows:

```
ARIA: Attribute " aria-label ", required for accessibility, is missing on node: 
<button class="md-no-style md-button md-ink-ripple" type="button" ng-transclude="" ng-click="click(item)" aria-label="">
<div class="md-list-item-inner ng-scope"></div>
</button>
```

Adding an `aria-label="tab-item"` on the md-list-item fixes the error, but the ng-click element is still removed from the md-list-item element.

---

**My code**

*list.html*

```
<md-list ng-class="'{{listClass}}'">
    <md-list-item ng-repeat="item in items" ng-class="'{{itemClass}}'" ng-click="click(item)" aria-label="" ng-transclude>
    </md-list-item>
</md-list>
```

*listDirective.ts*

```
function myList(): ng.IDirective {

     var directive: ng.IDirective = {
         restrict: 'E',
         templateUrl: 'components/ui/list/list.html',
         transclude: true,
         scope: {
             items: '=items',
             listClass: '@listClass',
             itemClass: '@itemClass',
             click: '&click'
         },
     };

     return directive;
 }

 angular.module('ui')
     .directive('myList', myList);
}
```

*myTestListPage.html*

```
<my-list items="$ctrl.items" list-class="testing" item-class="md-3-line" click="showOptions(item)">
    <span class="md-avatar">{{ $parent.item.code }}</span>
    <div class="md-list-item-text" layout="column">
       <h4><b>{{ $parent.item.code }} {{ $parent.item.title}}</b></h4>
       <p>{{ $parent.item.description}}</p>
    </div>
</my-list>
```

---

**Output I expect:**

I am expecting to see the following html code:

```
<md-list role="list">
    <!-- ngRepeat: item in items -->
    <md-list-item ng-repeat="item in items" class="md-3-line ng-scope md-clickable" 
                role="listitem" tabindex="-1">
        <button class="md-no-style md-button md-ink-ripple" type="button" ng-transclude="" ng-click="showOptions(item)" 
        aria-label="A0 A0 Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam ut ante erat.">
            <div class="md-list-item-inner ng-scope">
                <span class="md-avatar ng-binding">A0</span>
                <div class="md-list-item-text layout-column" layout="column">
                    <h4><b class="ng-binding">A0 Lorem ipsum</b></h4>
                    <p class="ng-binding">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam ut ante erat.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </button>
    </md-list-item>
</md-list>
```

[image: A picture of the list I want with ng-transclude]

***I Can click on an item in the list and the item fills up (and the click evenr is triggerd).***
*The button element is generated by the angular-material directive (it also sets the right elements on the button)*

---

**Output I get**

When running the code I get the following output in my browser:

```
<md-list role="list">
    <!-- ngRepeat: item in items -->
    <md-list-item ng-repeat="item in items" class="md-3-line ng-scope" ng-transclude="" role="listitem" tabindex="-1">
        <span class="md-avatar ng-binding ng-scope">A0</span>
        <div class="md-list-item-text ng-scope layout-column" layout="column">
            <h4><b class="ng-binding">A0 Lorem ipsum</b></h4>
            <p class="ng-binding">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam ut ante erat.</p>
        </div>
    </md-list-item>
</md-list>
```

[image: An image of the list I get with ng-transclude]

***I cannot click on the list and no event is triggerd. Also the styling is messed up***

---

**What I have tried**

- I have tried to add aan aria-label without any success.
- The list I created with the ng-transclude is should give exactly the same output as a normal list without transclude, so I made a test. The test gives the right output, the directive doesn't and I don't know why..

*My test code:*

```
<md-list>
    <md-list-item ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.items" class="md-3-line" ng-click="showOptions(item)">
        <span class="md-avatar">{{ item.code }}</span>
        <div class="md-list-item-text" layout="column">
            <h4><b>{{ item.code }} {{ item.title}}</b></h4>
            <p>{{ item.description}}</p>
        </div>
    </md-list-item>
</md-list>
```

**I am guessing it has to do with ng-transclude (won't be the frist time), but I cannot figure out why**

I have tried to add `<ng-transclude></ng-transclude` as an element inside the `md-list-item` but that messes up the css of the list. It seems that Angular-material is using css child selectors (`:first-element`) to style the list.

Comment: It is not enough that you add `aria-label=""` you have to give it a content, empty string is the default value. Anyway that is not your problem

Comment: @iberbeu adding aria-label="list-item" does fix the warnings. Yet the ng-click element is still removed. Do you have any idea what the problem is?

Comment: Is `ng-click` the only thing that is not working? It doesn't appear at all or is it just empty?

Comment: @iberbeu I just added some more info to the post. The output I get with ng-transclude differs from the output I would expect. That is probebly also the reason I get the aria-label warning.

Comment: In `myTestListPage.html` you don't have any button and in the template for the directive you don't have any button either. How are you expecting to have one like you show in your expected output. The output you get looks nice to me with the code you posted

Comment: @iberbeu Angular-material generates a button and sets the right attributes on the element. The expected result ('Output I expect') is generated by the test code (last part of my post). I would expect the directive to do the same. But yet it doesn't. That is why I am guessing ng-transclude has something to do with it. It is preventing the angular-material directive to work properly. 

But I still havn't found a way to get it working with ng-transclude.

Comment: what if you put `<ng-transclude></ng-transclude>` as an element inside `md-list-item` instead as an attribute?

Comment: @iberbeu I have tried that, but that messes up the styling. md-list uses css child selectors (first-element) so unfortunately that doesn't work.